# Pullback of volume form and pushforward of the induced (signed) measure

Tags: measure-theory, differential-geometry

What is the relationship between the pushforward of a smooth measure and the pullback of the corresponding differential form?

In other words, consider two manifolds $M$, $N$, a diffeomorphism $f : M \to N$, and a volume form $\omega$ on $M$. Denote by $\mu_\omega$ the (signed or not) measure induced on $M$ by $\omega$. Is it true that
\begin{equation}
f_\sharp \mu_\omega = \mu_{(f^{-1})^* \omega} ?
\end{equation}

The same question (and answer) should also be true for densities.

Comment: what is the measure induced by a differential form? maybe you mean the density form induced by $\omega $?

Comment: @Masacroso the measure here is induced by a *volume form*, not an arbitrary top-form. (Although, one has to choose the right orientation in order to have a positive measure.)

Comment: @OP Hint: write $\omega$ in local coordinates and $\mu_{\omega}$ as an absolutely continuous measure with respect to the Lebesgue measure in the corresponding chart, and apply the pullback. This should give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following the hint in the comments.

Let $(U, x, V)$ be an oriented chart and $h : U \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $\omega = h \mathrm{d}x_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \mathrm{d}x_n$. Consider also a measurable set $A \subseteq U$, then $\mu_\omega(A) = \int_{x(A)} (h \circ x^{-1}) \mathrm{d} \lambda^n$, where $\lambda^n$ denotes the Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now, let $(f(U), y, W)$ be a chart that has the orientation induced from the diffeomorphism $f$. Then, for $q \in f(U)$, we have
\begin{align*}
    ((f^{-1})^* \omega)_q &= h \circ f^{-1}(q) \det \mathrm{d}_{y(q)} f^{-1}_{yx} \mathrm{d}y_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \mathrm{d}y_n, 
\end{align*}
so that if $B \subseteq N$ is measurable, then
\begin{align*}
    \mu_{(f^{-1})^* \omega}(B) &= \int_{y(B)} h \circ f^{-1} \circ y^{-1}(z) \det \mathrm{d}_{z} f^{-1}_{yx} \mathrm{d}\lambda^n(z)
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
    f_\sharp \mu_\omega(B) &= \mu_\omega(f^{-1}(B)) = \int_{x(f^{-1}(B))} (h \circ x^{-1}) \mathrm{d} \lambda^n \\
    &= \int_{x \circ f^{-1} \circ y^{-1} \circ y (B)} (h \circ x^{-1}) \mathrm{d} \lambda^n \\
    &= \mu_{(f^{-1})^* \omega}(B)
\end{align*}
by a change of variable.